# Angular $http service does not load json file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Hello angular experts!

I used this custom directive for a table ([implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/1758/)) but when I try to use $http service load that json array from a file, json is not loaded into $scope.items, I am a beginner in angular and on fairly advance javascript thus I need some help from you.

controller initialization

```
    fessmodule.controller('ptiListController', function($http, $scope, $filter) {
```

$http service call

```
    $http.get('data/ptis/ptis.json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.items = response.data;
        }
    );
```

browser console error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Scope.$scope.groupToPages (http://localhost:8000/app/modules/app/phone/scripts/pti-list-controller.js:75:49)
at Scope.$scope.search (http://localhost:8000/app/modules/app/phone/scripts/pti-list-controller.js:68:16)
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/app/modules/app/phone/scripts/pti-list-controller.js:117:12)
at invoke (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/js/angular.js:4185:17)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/js/angular.js:4193:27)
at http://localhost:8000/app/lib/js/angular.js:8462:28
at link (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/js/angular-route.js:975:26)
at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/js/angular.js:8219:9)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/js/angular.js:7729:11)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/js/angular.js:7078:13) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

so what I have changed from the fiddle is:

instead of:

```
$scope.items = [
    {"id":1,"name":"name 1","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 1","field4":"field4 1","field5 ":"field5 1"}, 
    {"id":2,"name":"name 2","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 2","field4":"field4 2","field5 ":"field5 2"}, 
    {"id":3,"name":"name 3","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 3","field4":"field4 3","field5 ":"field5 3"}
];
```

i have changed to this:

```
    $http.get('data/ptis/ptis.json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.items = response.data;
        }
    );
```

and also, I have tried using the service call as:

```
    $http.get('data/ptis/ptis.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data;
    });
```

and got the same behavior.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post your dir structure as well? is the response ok? Is the JSON valid? check on jsonlint.com

Comment: I don't see the entire code, is it possible that you tried using  $scope.items before response.data was assigned to it successfully?

Comment: @ta-run - yes, json is valid

Comment: @aurelius why are you using `.then()` in this case? can you try the `.success()` and/or `.error()` directly.

Comment: @ta-run you can see above, i have edited the question, adding that I have tried  calling the $http in your proposed way and got the same behavior...

Comment: @Or Guz - "$scope.items before response.data was assigned to it successfully" - this is a case for which i need your case... how can I avoid that in js? I have tried a sleep but without success

Comment: are you sure your path is correct? if json file is valid, then try putting the file into the same directory and casting the $http.get directly on it using `$http.get('ptis.json')`

Comment: yes, it is, i have tried using an non-existing file and i am getting a proper 404 - not found resource response

Comment: You are performing an async call, you can't use the items before the aync call is over. Can you move the code related to scope.items into the success method?

Comment: i have tried this: "$http.get('data/ptis/ptis.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data;
    });" which does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using the `$http.get` wrong. Try `$http.JSONP` this pattern:

```
$scope.items = {}; // <-- initialize empty object

$http.jsonp('/someJSONUrl').
  success(function(data) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    $scope.items = data; // <-- fill object with data
  });
```

You can't use `$scope.items` before it holds some data. That's why you have to initialize it first, as empty object/array then fill it with data and `angular` magic should do the rest :)

Comment: same behavior: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.groupToPages (http://localhost:8000/app/modules/app/phone/scripts/pti-list-controller.js:79:49)
    at Scope.$scope.search (http://localhost:8000/app/modules/app/phone/scripts/pti-list-controller.js:72:16)
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/app/modules/app/phone/scripts/pti-list-controller.js:121:12)
    at invoke (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/js/angular.js:4185:17)
    at Object.instantiate ...

Comment: I have updated my answer, note that you can't use object that doesn't exist yet. this should work.

Comment: ok, i see what you have done... and when the dom is loaded in the browser i end up with items = {}

Comment: it works, just wrap it into the controller callback and you are ready to go :)

Answer (score 1):

I just do something like this as mention in [document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and it work:

```
      $http.get('someUrl').
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });
```

Here the sample:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('JustCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.ptis = [];
    // Simple GET request example :
    $http.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/idhamperdameian/239cc5a4dbba4488575d/raw/0a2ea4c6c120c9a8f02c85afcf7a31941ef74d3a/ptis.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // this callback will be called asynchronously
      // when the response is available
      $scope.ptis = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="JustCtrl">
  <span ng-repeat="p in ptis">
        {{p.name}}, {{p.description}}, etc...<br>
    </span>
</div>
```

Or you may prefer to [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/idhamperdameian/ft90pq6r/).